# Array from random objects of array

Tags: objective-c, arrays, sorting, random

I have an array with 20 elements.

```
myArray = @[ obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4, obj5, obj6, obj7, obj8, obj9, obj10, obj11, obj12, obj13, obj14, obj15, obj16, obj17, obj18, obj19, obj20];
```

I need to randomly get 10 of these elements and put them in another array. How do I archieve this?

Comment: `arc4random_uniform()`, `for` loops and `- [NSMutableArray addObject:]` are your friends. And the documentation. And Google.

Comment: Do a [Fisher-Yates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) shuffle and pick the first 10 elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, use arc4random to generate a random number with the range of array.count, in a for loop that iterates 10 times. Within the loop, fetch the item at indexRandomNumber, remove from array and insert into new array.

Basic stuff. Alternatively, you could sort or shuffle the array (vcsjones) and grab the first 10 items.